# Add assemblies explorer in reference window C# (Visual Studio 2022)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I try to find Assembly explorer window in reference manager like on first screen [first_screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whPXW.png)

but in my **console C# project (.NET 6+)** reference manager doesn't display that menu and shows only Projects, Shared Projects, etc.

[second_screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArMWr.png)

I tried to use this MS instruction (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2022#assemblies-tab) for adding registry key buy it gives no result.

[third_screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUSTj.png)

Please, help me to solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: That's not going to work for .NET 6.0+. And you don't need it. References in .NET 6.0+ are either project references or references to Nuget packages. You _can_ directly reference a dll as well, but you normally shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

As PMF said this doesn't work with .Net.

When you create a (.Net Framework) project, it will look like this:
[image]

When you create a .Net project it will look like this:

[image]

If you have any packages that need to be added, you can use Manage Nuget Packages to add them.
[image]